# How to change a button when clicked in Vue JS and Tailwind CSS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, tailwind-css, vue-composition-api

I'm trying to do a Dark mode button toggle, the fist step that I want to make is a icon that changes when I click in the button, but my code isn't running.
That's my code:

```html
<button href="" class="px-2 mb-1" @click="isDark = !isDark">
        <img src="../Assets/Icons/moon.svg" alt="" class="w-6 h-5 hidden lg:flex md:flex" v-if="isDark = true">
        <img src="../Assets/Icons/sun.svg" alt="" class="w-6 h-5 hidden lg:flex md:flex" v-if="isDark = false">
        </button>
<script>
export default {
  setup(){
    const showSidebar = ref(false)
    const stayInDropdown = ref(true)
    const isDark = ref(true)
    return{
      showSidebar,
      stayInDropdown,
      isDark,
    }
  },
</script>
```

Comment: Do you get an error message when you run this? If so, post it in your question. Also, a better way to do this would be to make a computed property called something like imgSrc, which returns one url if isDark is true and another if false, and then in your template, just have one <img> tag, like this: <img :src="imgSrc" class=".....">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`v-if="isDark = true"` means assigning `true` to `isDark` not comparing them, the comparison should be like `v-if="isDark === true"` but you could just do `v-if='isDark'`:

```html
 <img v-if='isDark' src="../Assets/Icons/moon.svg" alt="" class="w-6 h-5 hidden lg:flex md:flex" >
 <img v-else src="../Assets/Icons/sun.svg" alt="" class="w-6 h-5 hidden lg:flex md:flex" >
```